# jQuery fired in quick succession causes issues

Tags: jquery

Im making a comparison chart whereby a user floats over a feature and a small box (div) slides out giving details (say 'somethingBox1')

I have this working fully, however I am having problems caused when the mouse leaves one active area (an image with id="something1") to another bedore the end of the slide animation (image id="something2" lets say)

It seems that the browser isnt waiting for the previous line/animation to complete before running the next event, and causing issues such as the box(s) getting confused as to if it is visible or not.

I am firing this code for each element:

```
$('#something1').mouseleave(function() {$("#somethingBox1").animate({width:'toggle'},0);});
$('#something1').mouseover(function(){timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {$("#somethingBox1").animate({width:'toggle'},0);}, 350);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), which will stop any current animations. I like to have the animation finish animating (instantly) to ensure that the new animation behaves as expected.

Something like this:

```
$('#something1').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).wait(350).animate({width:'toggle'}, 0);
    },            
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({width:'toggle'},0);
    }
);
```

*(I've not tested this code.)*

Comment: Thanks, however it didnt really seem to stop the issue

Answer (score 0):

Having read more around the subject i came across the call function on complete,

I added  function(){} to the end of each .animate function, and it seems to make the browser wait (tested in ie, chrome, safari, opera, firefox)

```
$('#infolink6').mouseleave(function() {$("#infoBox6").animate({width:'toggle'},350, function(){});});
$('#infolink6').mouseover(function(){timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {$("#infoBox6").animate({width:'toggle'},350, function(){});}, 0);});
```